# llvm - Pass arguments to a pass

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir, llvm-gcc, llvm-c++-api

I need to tell the pass to look out for a specific function in the file. And I want to specify which function to look out for 'on the go' i.e when I run the pass. Any idea how I can do that? It's sort of like passing arguments to a function in theory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a command line option using `cl::opt<string>` and set it when running your pass.

Alternatively, if you are producing an IR from C or C++ using clang, you can utilize `__attribute((__annotate__(("foo"))))` to mark functions you are interested in.